# Accesing column name inside lapply

Tags: r

I use 'deparse(substitute(x))' from inside my function to get the name of the dataframe column passed as argument. It works great... but not with 'lapply'

```
myfun <- function(x)
{
  return(deparse(substitute(x)))
}

a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5,5)
df<-data.frame(a,b)
myfun(df$a)

[1] "df$a"
```

but, with 'lapply'...

```
lapply(df, myfun)
$a
[1] "X[[i]]"

$b
[1] "X[[i]]"
```

How can I get the name inside 'lapply'?

EDIT: I need to access not the column name but the FULL NAME (dataFrameName$varName)

Comment: Do you need `deparse/substitute`, you can use `Map(\(x, nm) nm, df, names(df))`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well. I need the full name (df$a), not only the column name...

Answer (score 0):

You can use colnames() :

```
f=function(d) {
   paste0(deparse(substitute(d)),"$",colnames(d))
}
```

Comment: I can't use this code inside the function, as I don't know the name of the dataframe inside it. I can only refer to 'x' (the variable passed as parameter).

Comment: thanks for the edit. The problem is that this solution does not work with 'lapply'. When invoking the function directly, deparse(substitute(x)) returns the variable name as a string, but, inside a 'laply', it returns "x[[i]]"

Comment: I think i misendurstood your problem. Maybe try   paste0(deparse(substitute(unlist(d))),"$",colnames(d))
}

Comment: Nope, sorry. It returns "unlist(X[[i]])" instead "X[[i]]" :)